# Using more threads in play framework with akka http server

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, akka

We have a web server that is running in production from past year and have no issues but recently there is a surge in the user base and since then we see severe slowness in the business hours and we are sometime seeing server going unresponsive as well so this is a severe problem for us.

We observe the max utilization in the DB side is at max 8 active connections and no more. So, we have narrowed down the problem to ‘Play framework or the akka server is allowing only a limited thread pool to manage all the load and thus causing the bottleneck’.

Being fairly new to the play framework and akka http server, we have tried the below configs in various combinations but still not seeing increased thread pool in the run time. It is always 8.
Note: This ‘8’ is seen consistent on a pc with 8 logical cores and on our production server that has 6 cores.

Thread name sample for reference :

> application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3

Sample config below:

```
#akka.action.default-dispatcher.executor = "fork-join-executor" akka.action.default-dispatcher.executor = "thread-pool-executor"
#akka.action.default-dispatcher.throughput = 100 akka.action.default-dispatcher.thread-pool-executor.fixed-pool-size = 300
#akka.action.default-dispatcher.thread-pool-executor.core-pool-size-min = 2
#akka.action.default-dispatcher.thread-pool-executor.core-pool-size-factor = 2.0
#akka.action.default-dispatcher.thread-pool-executor.core-pool-size-max = 10
#akka.action.default-dispatcher.fork-join-executor.parallelism-max = 24
 
akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-connections = 20
```

Comment: I don't think this statement: "Play framework or the akka server is allowing only a limited thread pool to manage all the load and thus causing the bottleneck" is a good conclusion. Akka can have a lot of concurrency on a very small number of physical threads. And 8 threads for 6 core machine doesn't seem too far. (IIRC the recommended  is 1.7*number of cores, which would be 10.)

Comment: But, in general, I think this question (which is essentially "why is my application slow") is too broad for StackOverflow. Maybe contact Lightbend for a support contract/consulting? (Disclosure: Lightbend is my ex-employer). Perhaps reduce it to a specific question around connection pooling.

Comment: Also, please repost more of the config and make sure it is readable. I believe you only posted one line and a bunch of comments. The number of HTTP connections is probably unrelated to the number of db connections.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, it's hard to give a definitive answer but in addition to Akka thread pool executor size that might need some increase in case of blocking calls, there is also a configuration for database pool:

```
play.db.prototype.hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 20
```

I'd recommend reading both section of the official documentation:

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase#Using-a-CustomExecutionContext
- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase#Configuring-the-connection-pool